# Warning: architectures 'armv7 armv7s' didn't contain all required architectures 'arm64'

Tags: ios, xcode

There is a warning in a Xcode project:

> crypto was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libcrypto.a'
>   because its architectures 'armv7 armv7s' didn't contain all required
>   architectures 'arm64'sasl2 was rejected as an implicit dependency for
>   'libsasl2.a' because its architectures 'armv7 armv7s' didn't contain
>   all required architectures 'arm64'ssl was rejected as an implicit
>   dependency for 'libssl.a' because its architectures 'armv7 armv7s'
>   didn't contain all required architectures 'arm64'

What should I fix this warning?

Comment: try and remove the `ARM64` architecture from your project Build setting. Because the libraries you are using do not support the new ARM64 architecture.

Comment: @rckoenes it works! could you please put your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the ARM64 architecture from your project Build setting. Because the libraries you are using do not support the new ARM64 architecture.

Comment: Does choosing "Standard Architectures" mean that the app will not work on new iPhones and iPads?

Comment: No, the new A7 processor is able to run 32bit apps. Other which the new devices can not run older apps, which they can/.

Answer (score 5):

Removing ARM64 is no longer an option…

> Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.

Answer (score 4):

This settings worked for me. Note Build Active Architecture Only settings for debug and release

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Removing the $(ARCHS_STANDARD) from the Architectures and replace it with armv7,armv7s solve the problem